# eclipse Ant Build package does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to generate a `.jar` in eclipse (Run as Ant Build) and I get errors like this one about the Apache's jars I added:

```
[javac] *path...*: error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
```

The jars were add from `BuildPath` `->` `Add External Jar`.

Did I miss any step?

Comment: Do not use ant anymore. Use maven or gradle

Comment: Have you added those jar dependencies into path in your Ant build.xml?

Comment: The Eclipse build path is not used in an Ant build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure compilation path in your build.xml
It could be done like this

```
<path id="main.classpath">
  <fileset dir="<directory with your jar dependencies>">
     <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
```

And then add link to that path into your `javac` task

```
<javac destdir="<directory where to store class files>" srcdir="<directory with java files>" debug="on" compiler="modern">
     <classpath refid="main.classpath"/> <!-- this is where you tell javac which path to use -->
</javac>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I still have a problem. The case is I'm using apache poi and I want to incluide the poi-ooxml.jar and if I put it manually in build.xml, the compiled jar doesn't work as it should with poi-ooxml (to work with XSSFWorkbook). How can I make it work? The poi.jar doesn't incluide XSSF. I'm sorry for my explanation, I'm so noob at this. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask new question with your build.xml and exact error message